# Foreshortened Curved Arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I need to show the rotational symmetries of a tetrahedron, and I've settled on using Sketch-generated TikZ code. I've included \usepackage{tikz}, \usetikzlibrary{arrows} and \usepackage{pstricks} so far.
I'm happy with everything except the arrow showing rotation about the axis in the following code:

```
% Sketch output, version 0.3 (build 7, Fri Feb 24 21:22:17 2012)
% Output language: PGF/TikZ,LaTeX
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\draw[color=blue](-.068,-.403)--(-.275,-1.609);
\draw[color=blue](.07,.402)--(-.068,-.403);
\filldraw[fill=white](.683,-.683)--(-.233,-.111)--(-.82,-.122)--cycle;
\filldraw[fill=lightgray](-.233,-.111)--(.372,.916)--(-.82,-.122)--cycle;
\filldraw(-.82,-.122) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[fill=white](.683,-.683)--(.372,.916)--(-.233,-.111)--cycle;
\filldraw(.683,-.683) circle (2pt);
\filldraw(.372,.916) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=blue](.071,.403)--(.07,.402);
\draw[color=blue](.277,1.609)--(.071,.403);
\filldraw(-.233,-.111) circle (2pt);
\fill[black,font=\footnotesize]
        (.683,-.683) node [below right] {$X$}
        (.372,.916) node [right] {$Y$}
        (-.233,-.111) node [right] {$Y$}
        (-.82,-.122) node [below left] {$X$};\draw (.208,1.207)+(-60:.25)
        [yscale=1.3,->] arc(-60:240:.25);\end{tikzpicture}% End sketch output
```

How can I get the arc (drawn in the final line) to be foreshortened so it actually looks like rotation around the axis (drawn in blue)? Better yet, is there a way to describe this in Sketch, or any other tikz-code generating environment? If you want, I can edit and include the Sketch code that generated this scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `yscale=1.3` on the final line to a value somewhat less that `1` helps a lot.  You can avoid accidental overlap by adjusting the start angle from `-60` to `-40`, on the last line and previous line.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\draw[color=blue](-.068,-.403)--(-.275,-1.609);
\draw[color=blue](.07,.402)--(-.068,-.403);
\filldraw[fill=white](.683,-.683)--(-.233,-.111)--(-.82,-.122)--cycle;
\filldraw[fill=lightgray](-.233,-.111)--(.372,.916)--(-.82,-.122)--cycle;
\filldraw(-.82,-.122) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[fill=white](.683,-.683)--(.372,.916)--(-.233,-.111)--cycle;
\filldraw(.683,-.683) circle (2pt);
\filldraw(.372,.916) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=blue](.071,.403)--(.07,.402);
\draw[color=blue](.277,1.609)--(.071,.403);
\filldraw(-.233,-.111) circle (2pt);
\fill[black,font=\footnotesize]
        (.683,-.683) node [below right] {$X$}
        (.372,.916) node [right] {$Y$}
        (-.233,-.111) node [right] {$Y$}
        (-.82,-.122) node [below left] {$X$};\draw (.208,1.207)+(-40:.25)
        [yscale=0.5,->] arc(-40:240:.25);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not beautiful, but probably a little better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}      

\begin{document}
% Sketch output, version 0.3 (build 7, Fri Feb 24 21:22:17 2012)
% Output language: PGF/TikZ,LaTeX
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\draw[color=blue](-.068,-.403)--(-.275,-1.609);
\draw[color=blue](.07,.402)--(-.068,-.403);
\filldraw[fill=white](.683,-.683)--(-.233,-.111)--(-.82,-.122)--cycle;
\filldraw[fill=lightgray](-.233,-.111)--(.372,.916)--(-.82,-.122)--cycle;
\filldraw(-.82,-.122) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[fill=white](.683,-.683)--(.372,.916)--(-.233,-.111)--cycle;
\filldraw(.683,-.683) circle (2pt);
\filldraw(.372,.916) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=blue](.071,.403)--(.07,.402);
\draw[color=blue](.277,1.609)--(.071,.403);
\filldraw(-.233,-.111) circle (2pt);
\fill[black,font=\footnotesize]
        (.683,-.683) node [below right] {$X$}
        (.372,.916) node [right] {$Y$}
        (-.233,-.111) node [right] {$Y$}
%        (-.82,-.122) node [below left] {$X$};\draw (.208,1.207)+(-60:.25)
 (-.82,-.122) node [below left] {$X$};\draw (.308,1.307)+(-60:.25)
%        [yscale=1.3,->] arc(-60:240:.25);\end{tikzpicture}% End sketch output
    [xscale=0.9,yscale=.4,->,rotate=30] arc(-40:290:.25);\end{tikzpicture}% End sketch output


\end{document}
```

[image]